# Fetch API con JavaScript "token"

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, tokens

Hola que tal recién estoy adentrándome con las API's, y a continuación estoy consumiendo una APi publica de prueba.

> **Mi pregunta sería ¿cómo puedo integrarle el token para consumir dicha API en caso de que la API sea privada?, teniendo en cuenta que el token ya lo conozco**

```js
var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido');
function mostrar() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
        (data.results[0])
            contenido.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${data.results['0'].picture.large}">
            <p>Nombre: ${data.results['0'].name.title +' ' + data.results['0'].name.last +' ' + data.results['0'].name.last}</p>
            `
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API | REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body style="background: rgb(238, 209, 189);">
    <h2 class="subtitulo">API REST</h2>
    <button class="btn" onclick="mostrar()">Click</button>

    <div id="contenido">
    </div>

</body>
<script src="js/rest-api.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: No comprendo tu pregunta, como está formulada actualmente, diría que si el API es publica, probablemente no tengas forma de modificarla. Para cambiarle cualquier cosa tendrías que tener acceso a su código fuente, modfiicarlo y luego tener los accesos y permisos para desplegarla en sus servidores ya con el cambio que quieras, por ejemplo, el uso de _tokens_.

Comment: @jachguate creo que la logre comprender, la pregunta es enrealidad mas sencilla, poniendola en terminos seria: "donde rayos uso o pongo la API key para poder usar la API en caso de ser privada?", ahora bien, amgio Luis, para poder saber eso tendras que tener en cuenta que no todas las `API` se acceden por igual, pues algunas las credenciales tienen que ir incluidas en la `URL` con un parametro especifico, otras requeriran esa informacion en los headers de la peticion.

Comment: En pocas palabras, esto siempre dependera de como este configurado el acceso a la API, si tu dices que tienes la API key, solo es cuestion de mirar la documentacion de la API para saber como integrarla y poder usar entonces la API con esa API key.

Comment: @Riven, tu has pasado de _token_ a _API key_ como si fuesen lo mismo, y yo sigo preguntándome en realidad qué es lo que quiere hacer el AP. Me temo que estamos ante el típico [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/21).

Comment: Por lo tanto nosotros no podemos darte respuesta a esta pregunta sin conocer cual es la API. pero ojo, nosotros no necesitamos la API key, solo saber que API key para conocer su documentacion, de resto, sin mas informacion que nos proveas no es posible decirte exactamente que debes hacer, ya que esto varia en funcion de la API que estes usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente los "token" se envian por medio un header de http, entonces para mandarlo usando fetch tienes que agregar el objeto headers de la API

```
var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido');
function mostrar() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api',
     headers: {
       "Authorization": "Bearer API_TOKEN", //Agregado
     },
     )
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
        (data.results[0])
            contenido.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${data.results['0'].picture.large}">
            <p>Nombre: ${data.results['0'].name.title +' ' + data.results['0'].name.last +' ' + data.results['0'].name.last}</p>
            `
    })
}
```

En los headers enviado tiene que ir lo que requiera el API para autenticarte, hay muchas formas de enviar headers de autenticacion